# Related List Issue Communities

Tags: community

I have a community enabled. On Opportunity there is a related list which shows an object that has lookup to my opportunity. I have provided permissions and everything. But I can not see that custom object when logged in as that user in communities.

Things checked.

1. Profile
2. OWD is Private, But that user is owner of that custom object
3. Its in Page Layout.
4. Tab is there. Can create new record using tabs.
   [image]

In community builder even i can see it . But when i log in as that user, unable to see that related list, While I am able to see Contact Roles,Files etc related list. Confused. :?

Any points here is appreciated.

Comment: Is the tab added and visible to the community?

Comment: Yes. Updated that in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Fixed it . The fields i made visible in Page Layout of related list the profile didn't have access to them. Provided access to those fields, voila working. :)